# Define the level of the loop when searching data in xml jqxGrid parameter

Tags: jquery, xml, jqxgrid

When someone defines the root and the record with jqxGrid to search an xml file, are there any parameters to define the child level for the specific map?

for example an xml:

```
<students>
    <student>
        <Name>name1</Name>
        <Age/>
        <student>
            <Name>name1.1</Name>
            <Age>age1.1</Age>
        </student>
    </student>
</students>
```

now setting the source as:

```
var source = {
        datatype="xml,
        datafields:[
             {name:"Name" , map:"Name" , type="string"},
             {name:"Age" , map:"Age" , type="string"}
        ],
        root:"students",
        record:"student",
        url: //link to the xml
};
```

and creating the grid after at the age field there is the age of the child student and also the parent student. So as I checked it writes every child with the specific tag name no matter the tree-level.

Is there a way to define the level of search?

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 0):

Some help [here](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdataadapter/jquery-data-adapter.htm).But the question remains.

```
var source = {
    datatype="xml",
    datafields:[
         {name:"Name", type="string"},
         {name:"Age",  type="string"}
   ],
    hierarchy: {
    // defines the root and record of each hierarchy level.
        root: 'student',
    },
    root: "students",
    record: "student",
    url: "http://link/to/the.xml"
};
```